# How to use specific element of one to many relationship in whereHas (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, relationship

I want to get data list , which has many relational rows in another table.
I need to check specific row of relational rows for getting data list from first, for example with it can be the first one and second ... (some conditions), but in whereHas you know that we are checking all elements.

```
$shipments->whereHas('shipment_stops', function ($q) use ($startDate) {
               $q->where('departure_date', '>=', $startDate) ;
            });
```

This will check all shipment_stops, but I want to check only the last stop with the specific type (for example).

I know that maybe I can create better structure in DB, but anyway, I have this structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Has One Of Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)

```
public function latestShipmentStop()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ShipmentStop::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

..

```
$shipments->whereHas('latestShipmentStop', function ($q) use ($startDate) {
    $q->where('departure_date', '>=', $startDate) ;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it will not help me, because when condition in my query is not true for the latest element, then it continue check another element. So it will not work when condition is false for latest element.

Comment: So pls tell me what you want to achieve... could you describe the problem more detailed?

Comment: Yes, if I will use your code , first it will check latest element of relationships, but if condition will be false , so deprature_date < $startDate, then it will check previous element of latest relationship. and if that one will be true, I will get that shipment, but I should't get that shipment because the last element of relation is not matching with condition.

Comment: No, it won't check previous element of latestOfMany because it will ALWAYS be the last record of many.

Comment: latestOfMany does't exist in Laravel 7, project is Laravel 7, I can't use it , what can you suggest ?

Comment: Update Laravel somehow.. it's all in docs